# Blank (but not null) columns - PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql

Doing by:

```
select * from ja_customers where id = 8154501
```

I receive:[image]

You can see that all the required fields are "blank" with some invisible character, so they're not null, so they're valid (technically)

**Question:**

How can I see which characters are in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function like the one below and check if a column has a value of empty string (this function return null for an empty string) or an invisible character.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION get_as_byte_array(anyelement) RETURNS INTEGER[] AS $$
      SELECT
        CASE 
          WHEN length($1::VARCHAR) = 0 THEN NULL
          ELSE
            (SELECT array_agg(get_byte($1::bytea, a)) FROM generate_series(0, length($1::bytea) - 1) a)
        END;
    $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

    SELECT get_as_byte_array(name_first), * FROM ja_customers WHERE id = 8154501;
```

Comment: It returns me blank fields... Don't see anything - **get_as_byte_array** = null

Comment: So, as a_horse_with_no_name says, you have fields with empty string values

Comment: Thanks for you help - This might be subject for another question but, what would be the cause of it?

Comment: You should check your client application. For dba's point of view, just open logs for all queries for a while (log_min_duration_statement = 0 in postgresql.conf - dont do this in production db) and check which client sent those insert or update queries with empty string ('') value instead of null value.

Comment: Thanks! - If you have a better idea about how to find the statement - Because looking the logs for empty strings will not be easy. Anyway, have checked your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **get_byte** function to detect which character in specific offset:

```
SELECT *, get_byte(name_first,0) as firstChar,  get_byte(name_first,0) as secondChar FROM ja_customers WHERE id = 8154501
```